# Make all command returns error when installing prover9

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to install the automated theorem prover prover9 on Ubuntu 20.10. So I went to [this page](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emccune/prover9/download/) and downloaded the file "LADR-2009-11A.tar.gz". Then, I followed the instructions on [this page](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emccune/prover9/manual/2009-11A/) and executed the lines

```
zcat LADR-2009-11A.tar.gz | tar xvf -
cd LADR-2009-11A
make all
```

Unfortunately, the third line results in an error: "undefined reference to round" (I think).

The full output message is here:

```
     ~/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A$ make all
  cd ladr         && make lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make libladr.a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make[2]: 'libladr.a' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
cd mace4.src    && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
cd ../ladr && make libladr.a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make[2]: 'libladr.a' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
/bin/rm -f *.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
make libmace4.a
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o estack.o estack.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o util.o util.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o print.o print.c
print.c: In function ‘p_model’:
print.c:114:6: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  114 |      printf(s2);
      |      ^~~~~~
print.c:119:8: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  119 |        printf(s3);
      |        ^~~~~~
print.c:137:4: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  137 |    printf(s2);
      |    ^~~~~~
print.c:145:8: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  145 |        printf(s3);
      |        ^~~~~~
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o syms.o syms.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o ground.o ground.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o arithmetic.o arithmetic.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o select.o select.c
select.c: In function ‘select_concentric_band’:
select.c:236:5: warning: type of ‘min_id’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  236 | int select_concentric_band(min_id, max_id, max_constrained)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
select.c:236:5: warning: type of ‘max_id’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
select.c:236:5: warning: type of ‘max_constrained’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o propagate.o propagate.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o mstate.o mstate.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o negpropindex.o negpropindex.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o negprop.o negprop.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o ordercells.o ordercells.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o commandline.o commandline.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o msearch.o msearch.c
msearch.c: In function ‘next_domain_size’:
msearch.c:850:5: warning: type of ‘n’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
  850 | int next_domain_size(n)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ar rs libmace4.a estack.o util.o print.o syms.o ground.o arithmetic.o select.o propagate.o mstate.o negpropindex.o negprop.o ordercells.o commandline.o msearch.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o mace4.o mace4.c
mace4.c: In function ‘init_attrs’:
mace4.c:36:7: warning: variable ‘id’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   36 |   int id;
      |       ^~
gcc  -O -Wall -o mace4 mace4.o libmace4.a ../ladr/libladr.a
/bin/mv mace4 ../bin
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
cd provers.src  && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
cd ../ladr && make libladr
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make libladr.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make[3]: 'libladr.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/ladr'
make clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
/bin/rm -f *.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
cd ../mace4.src && make libmace4
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
make libmace4.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
make[3]: 'libmace4.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/mace4.src'
make clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
/bin/rm -f *.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o prover9.o prover9.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o index_lits.o index_lits.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o forward_subsume.o forward_subsume.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o demodulate.o demodulate.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o pred_elim.o pred_elim.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o unfold.o unfold.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o semantics.o semantics.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o giv_select.o giv_select.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o white_black.o white_black.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o actions.o actions.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o search.o search.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o utilities.o utilities.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o provers.o provers.c
gcc  -O -Wall   -c -o foffer.o foffer.c
gcc  -O -Wall -lm -o prover9 prover9.o index_lits.o forward_subsume.o demodulate.o pred_elim.o unfold.o semantics.o giv_select.o white_black.o actions.o search.o utilities.o provers.o foffer.o ../ladr/libladr.a
/usr/bin/ld: search.o: in function `search':
search.c:(.text+0x66ef): undefined reference to `round'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:66: prover9] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/utente/Downloads/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

I searched and searched, but I am but a humble user. I would be very grateful if somebody could tell me how to solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with make.  Your code is not safe, and the compiler is warning you about it.  Instead of what you have you should be writing:

```
printf("%s", s2);
```

etc.  If you really don't want to do that, you'll have to specifically disable that warning (by adding `-Wall` you've requested all warnings).

Oh, I see you're worried about the error at the end:

```
search.c:(.text+0x66ef): undefined reference to `round'
```

that's because your link line is wrong: you've added `-lm` at the start of the line.  It needs to be at the end; this:

```
gcc  -O -Wall -lm -o prover9 prover9.o ... ../ladr/libladr.a
```

should instead be:

```
gcc  -O -Wall -o prover9 prover9.o ... ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
```

Without seeing the makefile rules and variables we can't say how to do this.

Comment: Yes, exactly! The problem was, as you said, that the option "-lm" was out of position. Actually I did not write the files: they are old and were abandoned, and became obsolete. But, apparently, that is the only current "official" release.

In case somebody will suffer of the same problem in the future, let it be know that you need to change the options order 7 times in file prover9.src/Makefile. See also this page that speaks about the same problem https://github.com/theoremprover-museum/prover9/issues/3